# Filtering array of objects based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is there a way to filter an array of objects by a particular value that could be in any property?

Let's say I have this object:

```
var x = [
    {
        name: "one",
        swp: "two"
    },
    {
        name: "two",
        swp: "three"
    },
    {
        name: "aa",
        swp: "bb"
    }
];
```

With `Array.prototype.filter` I might do

```
x.filter(function(y){ return y.name == "two"; });
```

However this would return only one out of the two objects that have "two" as a value in any of their properties.

Whereas

```
function findValue( value ) {
  var y = [];
  for (obj in x) {
    for (val in x[obj]) {
      if (x[obj][val].match( value )) {
        y.push(x[obj]);
      }
    }
  }
  return y;
}
```

does the job, but is a brute force approach.
Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 5):

```
var arrOfObj = []; // objects you're sifting
var prop = 'whatever';

var matches = arrOfObj.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(k => obj[k] === prop));
```

You want a combination of [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which returns a boolean if any of the elements of the array match the condition, it also stops iterating the array (in this case the keys of each object) as soon as it finds a match. If you need cross-browser support (and for some reason aren't using babel) the ES 5 version of the above is

```
var arrOfObj = []; // objects you're sifting
var prop = 'whatever';

var matches = arrOfObj.filter(function(obj) { 
  return Object.keys(obj).some(function(k) { 
    return obj[k] === prop; 
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe include an ES5 version, to match the OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

Well the obvious thing is to combine your `for..in` loop with your `.filter()` function:

```js
var x = [{name: "one", swp: "two"}, {name: "two", swp: "three"}, { name: "aa", swp: "bb"}];

var filtered = x.filter(function(v) {
  for (var k in v)
    if (v[k] === "two") return true;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 3):

use an inner loop method to check individual property values

```
var val ="one";
var res = x.filter(function(item){
     return Object.keys(item).some(function(prop){
         return item[prop] === val;
     });
});
```